# Show that $K$ is a linear bounded operator on $L_{p}(\mu)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Considering $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ as a measure space, I need to show
that the following:

If $k: \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal {F}$-measurable function
such that
$$
  \int_{\Omega} \lvert k(x, y)\rvert\, d\mu(y) \leq c_{1} \quad \mu\text{-a.e.}
$$
and
$$
  \int_{\Omega} \lvert k(x, y)\rvert \, d\mu(x) \leq c_{2} \quad \mu\text{-a.e.}
$$
then $K: (L_{p}(\mu), \lVert \cdot \rVert_{p}) \to (L_{p}(\mu), \lVert \cdot \rVert_{p})$
defined as
$$
  (Kf)(x) = \int_{\Omega} k(x, y)f(y) \, d\mu(y)
$$
is a linear bounded operator and $\lVert K \rVert \leq (c_{1})^{1/
q} (c_{2})^{1/p}$ with $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

To do that, first I considered the function
$$
  g(x) = \int_{\Omega} \lvert k(x, y)\rvert \lvert f(y) \rvert\, d\mu(y)
$$
and I tried to show that $g^{p}(x) \in L_{1}(\mu)$ in order to show that $g(x) < \infty$ $\mu$-a.e., but I was not succesful. Doing this I would have that
$$
  \left \lvert \int_{\Omega} k(x, y)f(y) \,d\mu(y) \right \rvert \leq g(x)\, \quad \mu\text{-a.e.}
$$
and so $x \mapsto \int_{\Omega} k(x, y)f(y)\, d\mu(y)$ is $p$- integrable. Someone suggested me to use $\lvert k(x, y) \rvert = \lvert k(x, y)\rvert ^{1/p} \lvert k(x, y)\rvert ^{1/q}$ but I don't see how to use it.

Any suggestions please?...

Comment: Estimate $\int\int k(x,y) f(y)g(x)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$ where $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q, $ applying Holder and the suggested decomposition of $k.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compute the $L_p$-Norm of $Kf$. If this is $<+ \infty$, then the operator is well-defined in the sense that for $f \in L_p(\mu)$ we have $Kf \in L_p(\mu)$.
To show the bound on the operator norm of $K$ we have to look for a constant $C$ with $||Kf||_p \le C ||f||_p$. Let's try this taking into consideration the hint given to you:
\begin{align}
||Kf||^p_p = \int_\Omega \left |\int_\Omega k(x,y) f(y) d \mu(y) \right |^p d \mu(x)\le  \int_\Omega \left ( \int_\Omega |k(x,y)| |f(y)| d \mu(y) \right )^p d \mu(x)
\end{align}
by triangle inequality for the integral. Then we write $|k(x,y)||f(y)| = |k(x,y)|^{1/q} \cdot |k(x,y)|^{1/p}|f(y)|$ and use the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality to find
\begin{align}
&\int_\Omega \left (\int_\Omega |k(x,y)|^{1/q} \cdot |k(x,y)|^{1/p} |f(y)| d \mu(y) \right )^p d \mu(x) \\ \le &\int_\Omega \left (\left (\int_\Omega |k(x,y)| d\mu(y)  \right )^{1/q}\cdot \left (\int_\Omega |k(x,y)||f(y)|^p d\mu(y) \right )^{1/p} \right )^p d\mu(x) \\ \le &(c_1)^{p/q} \int_\Omega \int_\Omega |k(x,y)||f(y)|^p d\mu(y) d\mu(x)
\end{align}
Because the functions we now have are all positive a.e. we can use Fubini's theorem to conclude
\begin{align}
(c_1)^{p/q} \int_\Omega \int_\Omega |k(x,y)||f(y)|^p d\mu(y) d\mu(x) \\=(c_1)^{p/q} \int_\Omega \int_\Omega |k(x,y)||f(y)|^p d\mu(x) d\mu(y) \\= (c_1)^{p/q} \int_\Omega |f(y)|^p \int_\Omega |k(x,y)|d\mu(x) d\mu(y)\\
\le (c_1)^{p/q} c_2||f||_p^p
\end{align}
By this we first see that for all $f \in L_p(\mu)$ we have $||Kf||_p <+ \infty$ which means $Kf \in L_p(\mu)$ and we see by taking the $p$-th root:
$$||Kf||_p \le (c_1)^{1/q}(c_2)^{1/p} ||f||_p$$
or equivalently
$$||K|| \le (c_1)^{1/q}(c_2)^{1/p}$$

Comment: Very clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\|K\|=\sup\{|\langle Kf,g\rangle |\:\, \|f\|_p\le 1, \,|g\|_q\le 1\}$$ We will make use of the Holder inequality $$ ab\le {1\over p}a^p+{1\over q}b^q,\qquad a,b\ge 0$$
Thus for $u>0$ we get
$$|k(x,y)f(y)g(x)|\le {1\over p}u^p|k(x,y)||f(y)|^p+{1\over q}u^{-q}|k(x,y)||g(x)|^q$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$ gives
$$|\langle Kf,g\rangle|\le {1\over p}c_2u^p\|f\|_p^p+{1\over q}c_1u^{-q}\|g\|_q^q \le {1\over p}c_2u^p+{1\over q}c_1u^{-q}$$ For $u$ such that $c_2u^p=c_1u^{-q}$ the RHS attains the value $c_1^{1/q}c_2^{1/p}.$